# Cannot understand C++ map semantics

Tags: c++11

I don't understand the constructor statement in the following code. How can the iterator to the past-of-end element be added to the map as a key?

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class my_map {
    std::map<K,V> m_map;

public:
    my_map( V const& val) {
        m_map.insert(m_map.end(),std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<K>::lowest(),val));
    }
};
```

Comment: It is about [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), not syntax. So your title is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can the iterator to the past-of-end element be added to the map as a key?

It's *not* the key. It's the position of the insertion. By passing `end` you're saying append to the map.

The **key** that you're inserting is the first part of the pair. i.e. `std::numeric_limits<K>::lowest()`.

The **value** that you're inserting is the second part of the pair. i.e. `val`.

The docs for [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) are useful.

Answer (score 2):

> How can the iterator to the past-of-end element be added to the map as a key?

That's an incorrect conclusion. [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) has several overloads. The one that is use in your call is:

```
iterator insert( iterator hint, const value_type& value );  // Overload 4
```

which does the following:

> Inserts value in the position as close as possible, just prior, to hint.